# What is the XPath to get value if attribute is equal only to one of two possible values

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-attribute

Having the XML

```
<node attribute="value1">text</node>
```

what would be the XPath to extract the `text` if `attribute` is `value1` or `value2`? For any other attribute value I'm expecting no match.

What works for me is

```
/node[@attribute = 'value1' or @attribute = 'value2']/text()
```

Is there any shorter notation for the same? I don't want to duplicate attribute name twice.

Comment: Can you try `//node[@attribute=('value1','value2')]`?

Comment: it works, you can post it as answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your xpath version supports this, use

```
//node[@attribute=('value1','value2')]
```